# how to compare multidimensional array for same values in different defined keys

Tags: php

I couldn't find any solution for the following task - please help:
I want to get the folowing result for a multidimensional array if DTEND==DTSTART where SUMMARY-name is the same(similar):

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (

        [DTEND] => Array

            (

                [value] => 20180219
                [type] => DATE

            )

        [DTSTART] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20190220
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [SUMMARY] => James Brown (AB123)
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20180708
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [DTSTART] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20180704
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [SUMMARY] => Johnny Cash (xy987)
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20180225
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [DTSTART] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20180219
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [SUMMARY] => Bob Marley (DE456)
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20181230
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [DTSTART] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20181229
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [SUMMARY] => Elvis Presley (FG789)
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20190112
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [DTSTART] => Array
            (
                [value] => 20181230
                [type] => DATE
            )

        [SUMMARY] => Elvis Presley
    )
```

)

1. match:
   end:    [0][DTEND][value] = 20180219 - [SUMMARY] = James Brown (AB123) - different,can NOT be joined

start:  [2][DTSTART][value] = 20180219 - [SUMMARY] => Bob Marley (DE456) - different,can NOT can be joined

2. match:
   end:    [3][DTEND][value] = 20181230 - [SUMMARY] = Elvis Presley (FG789) - same,can be joined

start:  [4][DTSTART][value] = 20181230 - [SUMMARY] => Elvis Presley - same,can be joined

Comment: I don't think there is an existing solution for this problem. I think you just need to try solving it yourself, then if you get stumped, post the code you have tried and then we can help you.

Comment: That's exactly my problem that I haven't found anything similar that could fit my needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example this should work.

```
$matches = [];
$count = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($x = $i + 1; $x < $count; $x++) {

        // finds " (any uppercase letters or numbers)"
        $pattern = '/ \([A-Z0-9]+\)/';

        /// remove the numbers within parenthesis and compare summary values
        if (preg_replace($pattern, '', $arr[$i]['SUMMARY']) == preg_replace($pattern, '', $arr[$x]['SUMMARY'])) {

            if ($arr[$i]['DTEND'] === $arr[$x]['DTSTART'] || $arr[$x]['DTEND'] === $arr[$i]['DTSTART']) {
                $matches [] = [$arr[$i], $arr[$x]];
            }
        }

    }
}

var_dump($matches);
```